# Importhtml Query Extract Between String

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, xpath, import, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to find a formula that fits two tables

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML(A1,"table", 16), "Select Col4")
```

output is
Page 1/10Page 2/10Page 3/10Page 4/10Page 5/10Page 6/10Page 7/10Page 8/10Page
9/10Page 10/10
Another:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML(A2,"table", 16), "Select Col4")
```

output is
Page 1/3Page 2/3Page 3/3

I want to extract the digits between "space" and "/" Is there a way to do this in this formula itself?

I then tried this

```
=transpose(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"Page|/10","~"),"~",0,1))
```

This also doesn't work since I have to manually change /10 to /3 in the second formula

Is there any way to achieve this for both data?

The sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QV4ZIPcUqMXJcEzKqQmVF7QVWq7L-awVzY2QJ9hOMkU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A1:B)<=(1*{
 REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A1, "//option[@value='21']"), "\d+$"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(B1, "//option[@value='21']"), "\d+$")}), 
 ROW(A1:B), ))
```

[image]